# Why does this function not work for this specific instance

Tags: python, function, loops

So i have created this function which takes two arguments (a function with one argument and a list). its purpose is to iterate through the list and return true if every instance of the function is True (else return False). So for my attempt i have  this:

```
def all_iter(func, ls):
    i = 0
    c = True    
    for i in ls:
     if func(ls[i]) == False:
        c = False
        break
    return c
```

now these are the three examples i have used to see whether it runs properly and they should  return  :

```
>>>all_iter(lambda x: x >= 0, [1, 2, 3, 0, 4])
True
>>> all_iter(lambda x: x >= 0, [1, 2, -3, 0, 4])
False
>>> all_iter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, [100, 10, 2022, 12])
True
```

Now for the first two examples the result i get when i run this are correct but for the third one i get:
**in all_iter
if func(ls[i]) == False:
IndexError: list index out of range**. Can someone provide some help?

Comment: The `for` loop iterates over the *values*, not the indices. It's a coincidence that each value in the first two lists are also valid indices into the list. You are getting the expected answer in the first two cases, but your function isn't *working*. `if not func(i):`

Comment: Why are you doing `ls[i]`?

Comment: Consider doing `for i in range(len(ls)):` instead? Either that, or just doing `func(i)` instead of `func(ls[i])`.

Comment: There's no reason to consider `range(len(ls))` here; the indices are not of interest.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga to iterate through the values of the list

Comment: As an aside, `all` is already a standard Python function: `all(x >= 0 for x in [1,2,3,0,4])`, etc.

Comment: @timoleontsilikis Ok. Did you try seeing what `i` is? Did you do any debugging at all? Note, you are *already* iterating through the list, that is what a for loop *does*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop:

```
    for i in ls:
     if func(ls[i]) == False:
```

will only work if every element `i` of `ls` is also a valid index of `ls`.  In your first few inputs, all of the elements happened to be smaller than the length of the list, but you hit an `IndexError` on the last case because the values were much larger.

What you might have meant to do is:

```
   for i in ls:
       if not func(i):
```

Note that there is a built-in function `all` that simplifies this entire thing:

```
def all_iter(func, ls):
    return all(func(i) for i in ls)
```

or equivalently with `map()`:

```
def all_iter(func, ls):
    return all(map(func, ls))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run through the index in this way while keeping your function the same relative style if you are not comfortable with more pythonic solutions:

```
def all_iter(func, ls):
    c = True
    for i in ls:
     if func(i) == False:
        c = False
        break
    return c

print(all_iter(lambda x: x >= 0, [1, 2, -3, 0, 4]))
print(all_iter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, [100, 10, 2022, 12]))
```

Which returns False and True respectfully. If you want to have the value return as a closure of all() then it would be something along this line:

```
def all_iter(func, ls):
    return all(func(i) for i in ls)
```

the all closure will execute the function for each value in an inline lambda, which essentially does all your function does in a single line and returns a bool of true only if every element works with the function passed in.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
for i in ls:
```

by

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
```